# Swift: How can I get the records from the database according to the cell pressed

Tags: database, swift, xcode, uitableview

Is it possible to get the data from the external database when a UItableViewCell is pressed?

I managed to create a UItableView where I am displaying the data from the database. If I press a cell then all the data that are linked to it should be displayed. For eg. if I have 4 main categories in the database such as TOOLS, OTHERS, SECURITY, PETS and each of them has its sub-catecory and are linked with each other in the database. So if I click on Pets, it should filter out and only Show me CATS, DOGS, COWS, LIONS. When I run this SQL I am able to get the information but cant figure it this out on Swift.

UItableViewCell is in my FirstviewController and its the Main Category .
When I click here it goes to my destination VC and has the table again in here.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvawR.png)

DestViewController is the sub-category
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Uj8i.png)

My CategoryList_ViewController.swift

```
  import Foundation
    import UIKit
    import WebKit

    class CategoryList_ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBAction func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {

        get()
    }
    var values:NSArray = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        get();
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func get(){
        let url = NSURL(string: "c:\deskstop\mobiletec\assignment\assignment2\cat.php")
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
        values = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return values.count;
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryList_TableViewCell
        let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
        cell.categoryLabel.text = maindata["NAME"] as? String
        return cell;

    }



    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "catView" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow  {
                let value = values[indexPath.row]
                let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! SubCatergory_ViewController
                controller.cate_Id = value["id"] as! String
                controller.catTitleRec = value["NAME"] as! String
        }
     }
    }
    }
```

my SubCatergory_ViewController.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

class SubCatergory_ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var caID: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var catTitle_Label: UILabel!
@IBAction func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {

    get()
}
var values:NSArray = []

 var catTitleRec  = ""
 var cate_Id = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    catTitle_Label.text = catTitleRec
    caID.text = cate_Id
    get();
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func get(){
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "c:\deskstop\mobiletec\assignment\assignment2\subcat.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    let postString = "a=\(cate_Id)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return values.count;
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! subCateListTableViewCell
    let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
    cell.categoryLabel.text = maindata["NAME"] as? String
    return cell;

}


}
```

and my subcat.php

```
<?php

    $connection = mysql_connect(........);

    $catefilter = $_GET['a'];
    if(!$connection){
        die('Connection Failed');
    }
    else{
        $dbconnect = @mysql_select_db($database_UNIASSIGNMENT, $connection);

        if(!$dbconnect){
            die('Could not connect to Database');
        }
        else{
            $query = 'SELECT category_group.group_id , category.NAME FROM category_group LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = category_group.category_id WHERE category_group.group_id =' . $catefilter ;
            $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

            $records= array();

            while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)){
                $records[] = $r;
            }

            echo json_encode($records);
        }
    }
?>
```

My first VC works fine but my second VC doesnot get the data

Thanks for your time :)

SK

Comment: Store response to values and then reload the UITableView. As I can see the response is just displayed you need to store it  and reload the  tableview

Comment: Hi Ankita, I m really week in this and facing problems, can u please help me how can I do this

Comment: Can you please show response after service call.

Comment: well, that all my code which i have worked. i dont know what exact response after service call you mean. when i load the first VC data is showing up, dynamically , and when i press the cell i dont get any response. my php file code is displayed . I really dont understand how to fix this

Comment: I have flagged this question as a duplicate of [Swift: Get database records according to the tableViewcell pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011897/swift-get-database-records-according-to-the-tableviewcell-pressed)

Comment: @SarahMalik You can't just create two identical posts since your first one wasn't answered.

Comment: when u click on the second image, you will see the screenshot, thats what i get, refer to: -    DestViewController is the sub-category enter image description here

Comment: sorry benjamin, i was working on it and i didnt realise i posted 2wice. this problem, has driven me crazy . I swear

Comment: What is print after this    `let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")`

Comment: I refered to a code somewhere just few hours back: the link is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYkZ47Rz8iU

Comment: not too sure, being struggling this for few days and I am badly stuck here in this assignment. my head is not working anymore

Comment: i didn't see you inserted any data into the `value` property in second vc

Comment: Hi Enix, how can i insert data into the value property in my second vc. do you mean this  statement: -  controller.cate_Id = value["id"] as! String
                controller.catTitleRec = value["NAME"] as! String

Comment: this statement is stated in the first VC  inside prepareforsegue

Comment: what you getting in" responseString". if having a value , please assign to "values" (you declared ).

I thought you copied and paste the same code and you forgot to change the variable name .   
replace

        values = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  
       // let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

Comment: I tried assigning the values but then, its giving few errors. can u guide me where can i assign the value. as u see in the screenshot, there is a number, this number is coming from the database and its a primary key, used as foreign key in the sub cate table as a ID. this number is passed from  the first VC to Second VC. and my subcat.php file  has the query which will filter out  with the ID and will display all the sub category assigned to this ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the cell that has been pressed, you need to call the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let value = values[indexPath.row]

    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubCatergory_ViewController") as! SubCatergory_ViewController

    vc.cate_Id = value["NAME"] as! String
    //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

First you get the `value` out of your `values` Array on the `indexPark.row`. Then you instantiate your second `viewController`.

Then you set your String value of `cate_Id` to the desired String value of your item `value`. And then you just need to present the new `viewController`.

If you're using a `UINavigationController` and you want a "back" button, then you use: `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`

If you just want to present the viewController, you use `self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment or uncomment whatever presentation method you prefer.